# Can we have an (optional) mixed review queue?

Tags: feature-request, review

### Can we have an *optional* mixed review queue?

This mixed queue would contain *all* pending reviews, combined in one queue. This should be an *additional* queue, not a replacement for the existing queues, to be used on low volume stacks.

### Rationale

I'm sure this is not really necessary on larger, high volume stacks such as Stack Overflow. But on smaller stacks, the review queues often show 1 pending in the Close queue, 2 pending in the Low Quality queue, perhaps 1 in the Reopen queue and that's it.

I always try to be a good little user and do my reviews. So it would be nice to not have to switch between the queues to review the few posts in each. I would like the option to peruse one queue containing all posts in need of reviewing instead.

Of course, this means it should be made clear which is which, when you get a Close review after a First Post, but it would have the additional benefit of showing a First Post that is also a Late Answer as *one* review, indicating that this post is *both*.

Comment: First post and Late answers often get the same posts, and have the same buttons - do you look at those posts in a different light? How easy would it be to distinguish that you are looking at a LA vs a FP?

Comment: @MichaelT that would be an additional benefit, seeing it as one review. I'd rather see _one_ post with a sign that says "First Post + Late Answer" so I know how to look at it.

Comment: IIRC, if I review a post in FP, I *don't* see it in LA when I go back to that queue. However, the point is that a LA has different implied review implications than FP (like going over the existing answers to make sure it isn't a duplicate of an earlier one).  And that if I finish the FP review for the post it doesn't remove the LA review from the queue for someone else to act on.

Comment: @MichaelT Exactly. When I review an FP, I would like to know that it's _also_ an LA< so I know that I need to check the existing answers as well (I usually do that now that I know they're often both).

Comment: That information is shown already on the side: "asked 5 years ago" is just a short scroll away next to the question along with "answers 8".

Answer (score 5):

I would personally not like it if I constantly have to switch from a Reopen review item to a Close review item, etc. The current distinction between them enables me to focus on one specific review type. When I am done, I will go to the next queue.

If your proposal gets implemented, I am afraid I will often mess up since I missed I switched from one review item type to another, without noticing that.

I am not against your proposal, but the above just worries me. If this gets implemented, we have to fix this some way.

Comment: I don't think the proposal is to *force* everyone to review all types of tasks in a single queue, but simply provide the option of doing that.

Comment: In general I am not against the proposal. I would not like it if it breaks more than it fixes @Ixrec